# Rails Datatable ajax not working - Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

so i've initialised datatables gem ok and its working properly. what i want to figure out now is how to implement the ajax api so as to update the fields automatically.

Here is what i have in application.js

```
$('#usertableadmin').DataTable({
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: 'users/',
      dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
          tableTools: {
              "sSwfPath": "http://localhost:3000/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
              "aButtons": [
                  "copy",
                  "print",
                  {
                      "sExtends":    "collection",
                      "sButtonText": "Export",
                      "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls",
                      {
                          "sExtends": "pdf",
                          "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                          "sPdfMessage": "Exported Users from website Database"
                      }
                    ]
                  },

              ]
          },
      responsive: true
    }).ajax.reload();
```

This is my usercontroller index action which is responsible for showing the users

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users}
    end
    # @columns = User.column_names
  end
```

and this is the html in my index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= link_to "Back", admin_path %>
<table class="display responsive no-wrap text-center" id="usertableadmin">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Activated?</th>
      <th>Admin?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.id %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place user, :name, url: "users/#{user.id}", cancel_button: 'X' %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place user, :email, url: "users/#{user.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place user, :activated, url: "users/#{user.id}" %></td>
        <td><%= best_in_place user, :admin, url: "users/#{user.id}" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

While with this configuration all users are listed, pagination is not working and also i get this error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I've read the datatables ajax api reload method but can't seem to find my error.

Comment: Check your stack trace, it's happening in the javascript somewhere. It should point to a line number in where it's executed  from your code.

Comment: can you collaborate i am a bit new at this..

Comment: With chrome for example open the console with Ctrl+Shift+J (Cmd+alt+J on mac). Refresh the page, and invoke the event that leads to your error. With the console ope, you should see a red message with an arrow next to it. Click on the arrow to expand to see the stack trace. Another useful tactic is turning on the setting "pause on uncaught exceptions" The console will pause with a breakpoint when an exception is thrown and you have the console open. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging has details on this